# jQuery plugins not working on nested pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I am working on this site (my rep isn't good enough to provide the home link) atm but I have a problem with [product listing pages](http://geetasfoods.com/products/lime-chilli-chutney-310g/) and the [tips and tricks page](http://geetasfoods.com/tips-and-tricks/), whereby what seems to be happening is a complete failing on the part of jMenu and jFlipBook respectively.

Since I did not write the original site nor have I used these plugins before I'm not sure why they're not working properly. You'll notice on the tips and tricks section if you inspect element and set the nav items to include the class jMenu (which jMenu should do automatically) the page becomes about 90% fixed (save for the submenus still being out of action). After digging around in the source for a while I've come to a dead end, so if anyone can shed any light on the matter it would be really helpful! Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the javascript console you will see errors pointing to your document ready code blocks.

You are using:

`$('document').ready(function(){`

when it should be:

`$(document).ready(function(){`

I would imagine that this is breaking your code.

Comment: Good shout but too no avail unfortunately =/..